# R: using libertine font in eps - error message

Tags: r, fonts, embed, eps

I am building a map in R that I would like to have the text to be shown in Linux Libertine font. Package `extrafont` is loaded, fonts have been loaded and the path to ghostscript is correctly set.

When I use the following command, R saves the output and everything works fine.

```
ggsave(file = foo.eps, plot = map, width = 15, height = 10, units = "cm", family='Linux Libertine Display')
```

However when I instead use `family='Linux Libertine'`, I receive the following error message:

```
Error in grDevices::postscript(..., onefile = FALSE, horizontal = FALSE,  : 
  unknown family 'Linux Libertine'
```

It seems that it can't find the font, which is weird as it is listed in the return of `fonttable()`. Any ideas how I can make R to use the font?

Comment: I'm working on loading the fonts from the package, but I did find this [package issue on GitHub which may cover your problem](https://github.com/wch/extrafont/issues/26). See the last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](https://github.com/wch/extrafont/issues/26) provided by user TomNash does indeed explain the problem and the solution:

The problem is that some fonts (and this includes Linux Libertine) have distinct font face names (Linux Libertine Bold, Linux Libertine Italics, etc.) but all share the same family name (Linux Libertine). The `extrafont` package cannot distinguish between those fonts, because it only looks at the family name (and in the above example Linux Libertine Display works, because this is a unique family name).

The easiest way to fix this is to locate the directory of the font table: `system.file("fontmap", "fonttable.csv", package="extrafontdb")` and then open the `fonttable.csv` and copy for all Linux Libertine fonts (or whatever fonts this concerns)  the font name into the font family cell. Then return to R and execute `loadfonts()` again to make sure R rebuilds the font table.

Comment: And Linux Libertine is correct, the point of family name is that's it's the same for the whole font family. You won't find distinct family names except in old fonts or fonts designed to workaround legacy software.